# Update Date from flexible HTMl Table with button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in my database which is called **webcam-fast**. The data from this table gets selected and written into a html table. Each Row of the table has a button which should update the corresponding data.
Here is a picture of my
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FejmR.png)
And here is the code I use to display my Table:

```html
html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<body>
<form class="row" method="post" action="">
    <div class="container vh-100">
        <div class="row form-center">
            <table class="table table-self">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Land</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ort</th>
                    <th scope="col">Bez</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cam-Url</th>
                    <th scope="col">Freigeben</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                
                $sql = "SELECT `ID`, `Land`, `Ort`, `Bez`, `Cam-Url`, `Bewertung`, `vkey`, `verified`, `Date` FROM `webcam-fast`";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        
                        $rowid = $row["ID"];
                        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                            $sql2 = ("UPDATE `webcam-fast` SET `verified`='1' WHERE ID = $rowid");
                        mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                        }
                    echo "<tr>
                    <td>" . $row["Land"]. "</td>
                    <td>" . $row["Ort"] . "</td>
                    <td>". $row["Bez"]. "</td>
                    <td>". $row["Cam-Url"]. "</td>
                    <td><button type='submit'  name= 'submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Freigeben</button></td>
                    </tr>";
                    
                }
                echo "</table>";
                } else { echo "0 results"; }
                


                $conn->close();
                ?>
            </table>    
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is also how it looks on the Page:
[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrYH5.png)
How can i now update the **verified** when the button is pressed. Right now it verifies all of my rows and not only the one I click.

**Thx Guys and sorry that the pictures are in german.**

Comment: You will need to have access to the specific ID so you can use it in the query WHERE clause and therefore only select the ONE record you actually want

Comment: And how would I be able to do that with my Code.

Comment: A little bit of research should get you started. Sorry but an answer would basically need to be a tutorial and that is not the purpose of SO

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction where i could find my answer?

Comment: Google `PHP form processing`

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
$rowid = $row["ID"];
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql2 = ("UPDATE `webcam-fast` SET `verified`='1' WHERE ID = $rowid");
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
}
```

If the button 'submit' was pressed then update the row where id is current row. So yes it will be true on all rows, and it will update all of them.

What you need to do is pass some sort of an ID while you're submitting. Then you can make a check like this:

```
if($_POST['verify_id'] === $row['ID']){ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you i will try it